# Python: adjust coordinates

Tags: python, coordinates

I have this Python script which should adjust the coordinates of a set of triangular elements. The script should change the coordinates of the nodes from an element towards the centre of gravity of the element. The below image is a sketch I made of the problem.

[image]

However something is wrong in my script, and I can't figure out what. The coordinates are not changed in the correct direction and extra new coordinates are generated, while I only want to adjust the existing coordinates.

**Does anyone know how to correctly program this in Python?**

```
coords = [[0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [0.0, 1.0], [1.0, 1.0], [0.0, 2.0], [0.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 2.0], [1.0, 2.0], [2.0, 1.0], [2.0, 2.0], [1.0, 1.0], [2.0, 0.0], [2.0, 1.0], [1.0, 0.0], [2.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0]]
elems = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11], [12, 13, 14], [15, 16, 17], [18, 19, 20], [21, 22, 23]]

#define vectors
def add_vectors(*points):
  new_x = 0.0
  new_y = 0.0
  for point in points:
    new_x += point[0]
    new_y += point[1]
  return [new_x, new_y]

def subtract_vectors(a, b):
  new_x = a[0] - b[0]
  new_y = a[1] - b[1]
  return [new_x, new_y]


def mul_by_scalar(vector, scalar):
  new_x = vector[0] * scalar
  new_y = vector[1] * scalar
  return [new_x, new_y]

#define triangles
triangles = []
for elem in elems:
    triangles += [coords[e] for e in elem]

#adjust coordinates
CM = mul_by_scalar(add_vectors(*triangles), 1.0/3)

point_to_CM_vectors = []
for point in triangles:
  point_to_CM_vectors.append(subtract_vectors(CM, point))

new_triangle = []
for elem in elems:
    for point, motion in zip(triangles, point_to_CM_vectors):
      new_triangle.append(add_vectors(point, mul_by_scalar(motion, 0.01)))

print 'triangles =', triangles
print 'new_triangle =', new_triangle
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I suspect that the value of `triangles` is not what you expect it to be. In fact it is `[[0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 0.0],
 [0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [0.0, 2.0],
 [0.0, 2.0],
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 2.0],
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [2.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 2.0],
 [1.0, 2.0],
 [2.0, 1.0],
 [2.0, 2.0],
 [1.0, 1.0],
 [2.0, 0.0],
 [2.0, 1.0],
 [1.0, 0.0],
 [2.0, 0.0],
 [1.0, 1.0]]`, a list of 24 2-points. Judging by the name "triangles", it should be something else. Anyway, `CM` is not the gravity center of these points, it's `[7.666666666666666, 8.0]` if you check it.

Comment: Assuming you want `triangles` to be a list of list of 3 coordinates, I'd initialize triangles as follows: `triangles = [[coords[e] for e in elem] for elem in elems]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a reworking of your problem using the vectorization operators provided by **numpy**.

```
import numpy as np

#define triangles
triangles = np.array([[coords[e] for e in elem] for elem in elems])

#find centroid of each triangle
CM = np.mean(triangles,axis=1)

#find vector from each point in triangle pointing towards centroid
point_to_CM_vectors = CM[:,np.newaxis] - triangles

#calculate similar triangles 1% smaller
new_triangle = triangles + 0.01*point_to_CM_vectors
```